# CSS: How to get the "main text" element to stretch it's properties to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have the following XHTML page followed by my intended CSS and would like the `main-text` div to go all the way to the bottom of the page so that `footer` and `footer2` appear at the bottom of the page and the `main-text` background carries through all the way to the bottom.

(N.B. The top margin and padding of "main-text" was intended as is)

Everything has been included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core-sheet.css">
    <title>MySite | Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>


<body>

    <div id="top-image"></div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="left-nav-links">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="thePages/GalerieImages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="thePages/contact.html">Feedback</a>
                </ul></div>

        <div id="main-text">

            <!-- 'Welcome' text, etc. -->

            <h1>Welcome to MySite!</h1>

            <h2>Introduction</h2>

            <p>Text Goes Here</p>


            <p class="footer">
                <a href="index.html">MySite</a> | <a href="thePages/GalerieImages/gallery.html">Gallery</a> | <a href="thePages/contact.html">Feedback</a></p>
            <p class="footer2">
                <a href="thePages/sitemap.html">Site Map</a> | <a href="thePages/imagemap.html">Image Map</a> | <a href="thePages/sources.html">Source Log</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here's the main style sheet (NB: filename is specified above as "`core-sheet.css`"):

```
/*Main Style Sheet*/

/* --------------- overview of page --------------- */

body {
    margin:             0;
    background-color:   #AAAAAA;
    color:              #000000;
    font-family:        Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:          1.1em;
    letter-spacing:     1px;


}


/* --------------- define body elements and style of page --------------- */


/* --------------- styles for all headings --------------- */


h1, h2 {
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
    font-weight:        normal;
    color:              #000000;
}


/* --------------- styles for individual headings --------------- */

h1 {
    font-size:          2em;
}


h2 {
    font-size:          1.4em;
}


/* --------------- paragraph style --------------- */

p   {
    font-size:          0.8em;
    text-align:         left;
    line-height:        1.2em;
    color:              #000000;
    padding-right:      200px;
    line-height:        120%;
}


/* --------------- page footers --------------- */   

p.footer   {
    font-size:          0.7em;
    text-align:         center;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:              #000000;
}

p.footer2   {
    font-size:          0.6em;
    text-align:         center;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:              #000000;
}


/* --------------- sidebar link positioning properties --------------- */


#left-nav-links {
    position:           absolute;
    line-height:        140%;
}


/* --------------- main text area of page --------------- */

#main-text {
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    height:             100%;
    border-left:        1px #000000 solid;
    padding-top:        50px;
    margin-left:        198px;
    padding-left:       50px;
}


/* --------------- lay out links neatly --------------- */

#top-image {
    height:              180px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image:    url(../images/MYZE.gif);

}
```

Comment: Static pages like this are messy when it comes to different resolutions (mainly on the extremes of really big or really small). You might want to be asking yourself if you're gaining anything from having it coded like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css needed,

```
/*Main Style Sheet*/

/* --------------- overview of page --------------- */

* {
  -webkit-box-sixing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
    margin:             0;
    background-color:   #AAAAAA;
    color:              #000000;
    font-family:        Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:          1.1em;
    letter-spacing:     1px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

}


/* --------------- define body elements and style of page --------------- */


/* --------------- styles for all headings --------------- */


h1, h2 {
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
    font-weight:        normal;
    color:              #000000;
}


/* --------------- styles for individual headings --------------- */

h1 {
    font-size:          2em;
}


h2 {
    font-size:          1.4em;
}


/* --------------- paragraph style --------------- */

p   {
    font-size:          0.8em;
    text-align:         left;
    line-height:        1.2em;
    color:              #000000;
    padding-right:      200px;
    line-height:        120%;
}


/* --------------- page footers --------------- */   

p.footer   {
    font-size:          0.7em;
    text-align:         center;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:              #000000;
}

p.footer2   {
    font-size:          0.6em;
    text-align:         center;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:              #000000;
}


/* --------------- sidebar link positioning properties --------------- */


#left-nav-links {
    position:           absolute;
    line-height:        140%;
}


/* --------------- main text area of page --------------- */

#main-text {
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    height:             100%;
    border-left:        1px #000000 solid;
    padding-top:        50px;
    margin-left:        198px;
    padding-left:       50px;
}


/* --------------- lay out links neatly --------------- */

#top-image {
    display: table-row;
    height:              180px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image:    url(../images/MYZE.gif);

}

#content {
  height: 100%
}
```

http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/uFbHK

One of the solutions here is to use table.

To tackle this, set the remaining height is to display:table for the container and display: table-row for the child. This way, if the container was set to be 100%, and you specify the display: table-row for the 1st child element to be fixed height and 2nd child element to be height:100%, the 2nd child element will have the remaining height needed to fill in the entire container.